# OpenCV Grab Last Frame Of Video Constantly

Tags: python, opencv

So far I am able to grab the last frame of the video, after modifying what I had before.
Now the problem persists to be that it grabs the last frame, starts on the last frame but then nothing after. The image is displayed on the GUI but it doesn't update even though it seems it should.
I'm quite new to python so any help would be awesome.

main.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import frame_counter

path = 'video.flv'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

template = cv2.imread('2.png',0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

while 1:

length = frame_counter.count(path)
print(length)
cap.set(1,length);

ret, img = cap.read()
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

print("Went through")

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.9
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,255,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('Detected',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
if k == 27:
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

frame_counter.py

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import count_frames

def count(path):

# count the total number of frames in the video file
total = count_frames(path, False)
return total
```

Comment: Try setting the current frame position:
`capture = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
count = capture.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, count - 1)`

Comment: I'll try this out in a bit, thank you for sure.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't update the image. I know OpenCV does process images slowly due to it analyzing everything I'm throwing at it but it hasn't updated in 2 minutes so I'm fairly certain it won't happen. Thanks for the suggestion though.